# i want to show my image without duplicate how can i do it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
      
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
                var imagetwo: ImageView
                var imagethree: ImageView
                var buttontwo: Button
                val images = mutableListOf(R.drawable.doctor,R.drawable.fish,R.drawable.sun,R.drawable.dog
                ,R.drawable.dolphin,R.drawable.elephant)
                val imagestwo = mutableListOf(R.drawable.flash,R.drawable.dinosaur,R.drawable.giraffe,R.drawable.monkey,R.drawable.rabbit,R.drawable.mikimouse)
        
                imagetwo = findViewById(R.id.imagetwo)
                imagethree = findViewById(R.id.imagethree)
                buttontwo = findViewById(R.id.buttontwo)
        
                buttontwo.setOnClickListener{
                    val randomone = images.random()
                    val randomtwo = imagestwo.random()
                    imagetwo.setImageResource(randomone)
                    imagethree.setImageResource(randomtwo)
                }
            }
        }
```

i want to show my image without duplicate in kotlin how can i do it can someone help me please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "without duplicate"?

Comment: for example when i click button " next " the doctor picture it shows again and i click next it shows sun picture and when i click next it shows doctor again its random but i dont want to show the same picture twice i want only one

Comment: And if it will be the last one? What will happen after click on Next?

Comment: my idea of app is : you click the right pic if its correct u click next the game show u 2 diff pic and u need to click to right one . last pic will make the game move to other page and make the game reset ( srry for my english ) but plz help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    var imagetwo: ImageView
    var imagethree: ImageView
    var buttontwo: Button
    val images = mutableListOf(R.drawable.doctor,R.drawable.fish,R.drawable.sun,R.drawable.dog
        ,R.drawable.dolphin,R.drawable.elephant)
    val imagestwo = mutableListOf(R.drawable.flash,R.drawable.dinosaur,R.drawable.giraffe,R.drawable.monkey,R.drawable.rabbit,R.drawable.mikimouse)

    imagetwo = findViewById(R.id.imagetwo)
    imagethree = findViewById(R.id.imagethree)
    buttontwo = findViewById(R.id.buttontwo)

    buttontwo.setOnClickListener{
        if (images.size == 0) return
        val randomone = (0..images.size).random()
        val randomtwo = (0..imagestwo.size).random()
        imagetwo.setImageResource(images[randomone])
        imagethree.setImageResource(imagestwo[randomtwo])
        images.removeAt(randomone)
        imagestwo.removeAt(randomtwo)
    }
}
```

}

Once we are done using a certain Image , we can then remove it so that it won't duplicate.

the `..` is used to define a Range in kotlin

Comment: it's not working game crashed :( but thank you anyway bro <3

Comment: What did the crashlog say ?

Comment: i didint see log i forget when i open the game it says close the app

Comment: Edited the answer , If you'd like to try - this should probably work

Comment: 'return' is not allowed here:68 / and i tried to remove return and start the game the image still the same and there is no random images